# date_default_timezone_set(“Europe/London”) does not return correct time

Tags: php, datetime, pdo

When I use the code below to set my default timezone and insert it into a database, the time is in-correct.

At the time of testing, the time was 11:56, but the database has it set at 06:56, **5 hours behind**.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO test (datetime) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Well, you do know you need to modify the timezone settings of MySQL and **not** PHP's?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, is there a set of instructions on how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: PHP and MySQL are two totally different processes; each has its own settings. Setting timezone in PHP has nothing to do with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the time in php

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$time_stamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO test (datetime) VALUES ('".$time_stamp."')");
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: That seems to produce the result `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in the database.

Comment: Brilliant, that's solved the problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Provided MySQL has information about timezone settings (it usually has):

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'
```

If there is no information about timezones, but there is in the server, you can load the tables in MySQL using the command line on the server, but that's server management:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql -p
```

If installing timezone tables is not possible, you can get the default timezone offset in the form `+hh:mm` with php and use it as `time_zone` in MySQL. This must be done, of course, after calling `date_default_timezone_set('<timezone_name>')`

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime_offset = $datetime->format("P");
$query = "SET time_zone = '$datetime_offset'";
```

Comment: Seems to produce the error `#1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Europe/London'`